# Serving static files in development

Tags: python, django

I've got some static files that are currently serving from Amazon S3. This obviously isn't effective because I can't `collectstatic` every time I make a minor change. Whenever I'm developing I want to serve from my project where the static files are collected from. The project structure looks partially like this:

```
myproject
-app
--templates

-myproject
--static
---app
----css
----js
----img
```

My `settings.py` looks partially like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/app'),
)

AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=94608000',
}

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
else:
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN


STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that if I'm running development (when `DEBUG` would be true) serve static files from the project, rather than fetching from S3.

At the end of my `urlpatterns` in `urls.py` I have `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`.

Finally, in my `base.html` I have:

```
<!doctype html>
...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/normalize.css'%}">
```

If I'm running with `debug=True` and I view the source of the page I see `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">` which isn't where the file is. If I run with `debug=False` and view the source I get`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<AMAZON BUCKET>/css/normalize.css">`.

What am I missing to serve locally?

Comment: I think you're missing the "second" settings. Remember you have multiple settings files! You can split the AWS code to the production related settings and reduce the "bloat" from the local ones.

Comment: I only have one `settings.py`  which is located in the same directory as my static folder.

Comment: What happens if you remove the heading slash? `{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}`

Comment: Ha, I never would have got that in a million years. Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a relative path to the `static` template tag, without the heading slash:

```
{% static 'css/normalize.css' %}
```